# How to use React Prompt with nested Routers?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Let's say I have 2 very simple Routers. Each of them is a separate component. 
First one is the ParentRouter:

```
<TopComponent></TopComponent>
       <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/child" component={ChildRouter}>
            </Route>
            <Route path="/outside" component={OutsideComponent}>
            </Route>
          </Switch>
        </Router>
```

Second one is the ChildRouter:

```
       <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/child" component={ListOfExampleComponents}>
            </Route>
            <Route path="/child/example" component={ExampleComponent}>
            </Route>
          </Switch>
        </Router>
```

TopComponent is displayed all the time on every URL.
When I am on **/child/example** I want to have a React Prompt displayed if I click a Link to the **/outside** or to the **/child** (the Link can be placed inside  **ExampleComponent** or **TopComponent**) or use back button to go back to the **/child**. 
How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found out what is the answer.
I added Prompt as it is intended in the Parent Router and deleted `<Router>` tags in the Child Router.